# Typescript thinks that an object parameter in a function is a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

A bit of context first. The following code was previously written in javascript and is slowly being migrated to typescript. Changes cannot be made to the `checkRecordsExists` function that require typescript as the file needs to remain in JS to avoid it breaking everything else that we use it in.

I've got the following function (express middleware) written in a js file:

```js
module.exports.checkRecordsExists = (Model, { idName = 'id', paramLocation = 'path', optional = false, checkSource = true, additionalChecks, idDbField = 'id' } = {}) => { 
    ...
};
```

and according to VSCode the functions object parameter which should fall back to an empty object are of type string

> (alias) checkRecordsExists(Model: object, { idName, paramLocation, optional, checkSource, additionalChecks, idDbField }?: string): (req: any, res: any, next: any) => Promise

This is causing the typescript compiler to complain when I try to call it like so in a ts file:

```
checkRecordsExists(dbService.CustomPage, { checkSource: false })
```

with the following error message:

> Argument of type '{ checkSource: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. ts(2345)

Any ideas on how to fix this weird error without using `//@ts-ignore`?

Comment: how do you import module that declare checkRecordsExists function ?

Comment: FYI you don't need to keep a file in Javascript to also use it in Javascript files, see [Migrating from Javascript in the Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html).

Comment: @jeremy-denis importing it using `import { checkRecordsExists } from '../../middleware/auth';`

Comment: @Etheryte ah sorry should've specified that the file that uses `checkRecordExists` is in Typescript but thanks for linking the documentation anyways :). Will update the post

Comment: Why don't you update `checkRecordExists` to have the correct types?

Comment: @Keith What's wrong with the current types? As they almost all have defaults then they can be used as types, the file is also a JS file so I can't tell it what parameters are which types

Comment: `also a JS file so I can't tell it what parameters are which types`   Yes, you can.. That's the whole point of declaration files.  Typescript is mainly for TS files, it can parse JS files, but it's never going to be 100%..

Comment: `Changes cannot be made to the checkRecordsExists`,  that's not a problem,  if your allowed to put a `thefilename.d.ts` file next to the same JS file, making a type for this is very simple.

Comment: oh interesting, I'll have a look into it. What do I need to look for when finding examples to do this?

Comment: I can knock you up a simple step by step, assuming your allowed to place a `thefilename.d.ts` file in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knocking up a declaration file for existing JS files is not as hard as it seems.   I must admit when first using Typescript it wasn't obvious how I could mix TS & JS together, so I though I'd knock up a very very simple example..

Ok, let's start.

Lets assume we have a very simple hello function inside a file called `test.js`

```
export function hello(a) {
  console.log(`hello ${a}`)
}
```

Now lets assume we always want parameter a to be a `string`, and for it not to return anything `void`.

all we have to do is create a file called `test.d.ts` in the same directory, the declaration would then be as simple as.

```
declare namespace JS {
  function hello(a:string):void;
}

export = JS;
```

And now when we import `test` into another TS file, you will get this->

```
import {test} from "./test"

hello('there'); /*this is fine*/
hello(123); /*Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.*/
```

Without the `.d.ts` file the type for `hello` would be `function hello(a:any):void`..

Another option, if you was allowed to change the JS file, but were not allowed to convert to Typescript,.  Typescript can use JSDoc syntax.  So doing the following would have the same effect.

```
/** @type {function(string):void} console logs hello + param*/
export function hello(a) {
  console.log(`hello ${a}`)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to more this types file to another directory for consistency? I've currently got a directory called `@types` with a `index.d.ts` file for some things required in express that I use. I've already specified in the tsconfig to point to that folder

Comment: @JoelAdams  The problem would be module resolution, I think it might be possible with some tsconfig settings, but it's not something I've ever wanted to do.  For me having the types next to what your typing for is way simpler, there is no tsconfig settings you need to change etc, so makes the code much easier to share / port.  I wish all 3rd party libs did it this way too, having to do thing like `npm install @types/react`, always feels clunky too me.  ps.  react module resolution works here, as there is a direct mapping from `@types/react` to `react`..